# Интервал выполнения действия

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять. как в js сделать интервал выполнения для нескольких объектов.

Например, есть такой массив

```
var data = {
    data1:{
        increment:1,
        innerTo:"#elem"
    },
    data2:{
        increment:20,
      innerTo:"#elem2"
    },
    dataN:{
        increment:400,
      innerTo:"#elemN"
    }
};
```

Он динамический, то есть данные могут добавляться и удаляться. Как сделать с заданным интервалом времени обход этого списка и для каждого данного выполнять определенные действия, которые там указаны?

например для data1 каждую секунду увеличивать значение на 1 и вставлять в элемент. Для второго увеличивать каждую секунду на 2 и вставлять в другой элемент. И такой список может изменяться.

Comment: `setInterval` пробовали?

Comment: Уже указал в ответе:)

Comment: пробовал. пока не выходит

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так через `setInterval`:

```js
data = [ 
        { increment:1, timer: 1000, innerTo :"elem1" },
        { increment:1, timer: 2000, innerTo:"elem2" },
        { increment:1, timer: 3000, innerTo:"elem3" }
]

for(let el of data) {
    setInterval( () => {
       document.getElementById(el.innerTo).innerHTML = el.increment++;
    }, el.timer);
}
```

```html
<div id='elem1'>1</div>
<div id='elem2'>1</div>
<div id='elem3'>1</div>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что до такого я тоже дошел. Но ваш код ровно как и мой почему то вставляет данные в последний элемент. А надо в каждый. проверьте и убедитесь. что данные идут только в последний.

Comment: Странно но у меня все записывает ,и данные идут во все сразу, как нужно.